# "Not Valid OOXML File" Error when attempting to combine 25 single-sheet files into a single workbook with 25 sheets

Tags: java, excel, file, apache-poi

I'm having issues with Apache POI when trying to combine multiple excel files into a single excel file. My program is currently composed of two Java classes. My main problem is I believe in FileList, whenever I create an Array of Files, I believe it just must not be maintaining the OOXML format, so I see the error in ExcelCombiner.java. I was hoping someone could assist with alternatives to my approach that wouldn't raise the error.

```
// FileList.java


import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileList {
    private File[] files;
    private String folderPath = "/Users/andrew/Desktop/MIMIC_DATABASE";
    private File folder;

    public FileList() {
        folder = new File(folderPath);
        files = folder.listFiles();
    }

    //Getters
    public File[] getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public File getFolder() {
        return folder;
    }

    //Tester
    public static void testClass() {
        FileList fileList = new FileList();

        int i = 0;

        for (File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            i++;
        }
    }

    /*
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testClass();
    }
    */
}
```

The other class:

```
//ExcelCombiner.java

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelCombiner {
    private FileList fileList = new FileList();
    private Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    public void createWorkbook() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("MIMIC_DATABASE.xlsx"));
        createSheets();
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        workbook.close();
    }

    public void createSheets() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        for (File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            Workbook fileBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            String sheetName = fileBook.getSheetName(0);
            //New Sheet in Workbook that we're copying info into
            Sheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
            //Old Sheet, fileBook should just be an excel file with one sheet
            Sheet oldSheet = fileBook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < oldSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                Row row = oldSheet.getRow(i);
                Row newRow = newSheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(j);

                    //Make sure to convert all old cells into String/Text
                    //Then copy them over to newCell
                    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
                    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    newCell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        ExcelCombiner excelCombiner = new ExcelCombiner();
        excelCombiner.createWorkbook();
    }
}
```

Comment: What file name prints `System.out.println(file.getName());` just before the error occurs? That file seems not to be a valid `OOXML` file.

Comment: TRANSFERS.xlsx is the name of the file, which seems like it would be valid

Comment: Where is this file coming from? What happens if you open this file using `Excel`? Does `Excel` show message or warning dialogs? What happens if you open this file using `Excel` and then simply save the file in `Excel` again? Is `apache poi` then able creating a `XSSFWorkbook` from that file?

Comment: Okay, I definitely overlooked that -- my files were in .csv so I converted them over to .xlsx and it worked. However, now I have an issue of after going through the loop, the file created at the end doesn't open properly in excel.